# Git show only current state of files on branch and delete commit history

Tags: git

I am new to git. I have a lot of unnecessary commits committed to my branch.
I want to keep the current state of files and remove all commits history. I don't mind resetting the branch. What's the best way to do this?

I think this should be something like

```
git stash
git reset --hard
git pop 
git add file
git commit -m 'commit'
git push -f origin
```

help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the *best* way to do what you want is firstly to turn all the local changes into a commit.

```
$ git commit -a -m "work-in-progress"
```

Then, use interactive rebase to squash the commits back to just before a given commit `<sha>`:

```
$ git rebase -i <sha>^
```

Interactive rebase brings up an edit window with a list of commits. For each one
you can specify one of several actions, like `pick`, `squash`, `fixup` and others. If you put `squash` for each commit, they will be picked and collapsed together, and you will be able to edit the commit message, which will be initially based on a catenation of their individual commit messages.

The interactive rebase workflow is one of the features in `git` that is really worth learning.